# Linq Where query option works strange

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a school database and I wrote a query to get students, who have only 5 and 4 marks (A and B in US). Here it is:

```
var selectGoodStudents = from student in context.Gradebook
                         group student by student.Student_Id into studentsGroup
                         where studentsGroup.All(x => x.Mark == 4 || x.Mark == 5)
                         let goodStudent = studentsGroup.FirstOrDefault()
                         select new 
                         {
                             Name = goodStudent.Student.Name,
                             Surname = goodStudent.Student.Surname,
                             MiddleName = goodStudent.Student.Middle_Name,
                             ClassNumber = goodStudent.Student.Class.Number,
                             ClassLetter = goodStudent.Student.Class.Letter
                         };
```

It works good, but i am dont understand one thing. I am suggest if the **where** statement gets **true** from operation **studentsGroup.All(x => x.Mark == 4 || x.Mark == 5)**, **studentsGroup** will be added to result of query. If **false** - not. And my query works in accordance with this suggession. **BUT**, if I will write in where statement an explicit construction, like this

```
where studentsGroup.All(x => x.Mark == 4 || x.Mark == 5) == true
```

the query will get **ALL** of groups from table. If I write **== false** the query would not get anything. I am don't understand this **very very**.

Comment: The easiest way to check what's going on is to check how does generated SQL looks like. Debug your code, put breakpoint after `selectGoodStudents` declaration and check what `selectGoodStudents.ToString()` returns using watch window.

Comment: Or monitor the SQL Server by SQL Profiler.

Comment: `x.All(..) == true` is equivalent to `x.All(..)`, so `x.All(..) == false` is simply the negation (which is itself equivalent to `!x.All(..)`) which says, "for this student (as the group is by student ID), only select him/her if they have grades of which *not all* are 4 or 5" (that is, if they have grades/marks like 1 or 3) .. maybe everyone *is* a "good" student?

Comment: No, not everyone. Only 2 good students in base =( If i write `x.All()` it will get good students. If i write `!x.All()` it will get bad students. If i write `x.All() == true` it will get all students, else - noone. Very strange.

Comment: Does "equals" work in this context? Also did you try to put the expression between parenthesis?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've found a bug here. When I try something similar I see quite different SQL queries being generated with and without `== true`. The query with `== true` has a bloated structure (in EF 6 even worse than EF 5!). I can imagine that EF trips over its own two feet here. I think you should turn it in: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced

Comment: I forgot to say that in my case the queries do have the same, correct, results.

Comment: May be just do the filter even before grouping by for more consistency.